# Unauthorized HTTP request .NET

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, authorization, httprequest

I'm trying to make HTTP request with Bearer authorization. I have a token, token is valid. Tried to do it 3 different ways: App, that request must be implemented in, POSTMAN, console app with a code generated with POSTMAN (C# - RestSharp) from the same POSTMAN call:

App POST method:

```
public async Task<TResponse> Post<TRequest, TResponse>(string requestUri, TRequest data)
    {
        LogInit(requestUri, HttpMethod.Post, data);
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri))
        {
            var token = await GetToken(_httpClient);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request))
            {
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw await HandleErrorResponse(response);
                }

                var responseObj = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<TResponse>();
                return responseObj;
            }
        }
    }
```

Console POST method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://***");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", "ARRAffinity=xxx");
        var body = @"{
            " + "\n" +
                        @"    ""amisPersonId"": ***,
            " + "\n" +
                        @"    ""name"": ""***"",
            " + "\n" +
                        @"    ""surname"": ""***"",
            " + "\n" +
                        @"    ""personalCode"": ""***"",
            " + "\n" +
                        @"    ""email"": ""***"",
            " + "\n" +
                        @"    ""phoneNumber"": ""***""
            " + "\n" +
        @"}";
        request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
```

Requests tracked with debugger:

[App request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXwNZ.png)

[Console app request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMrQB.png)

[POSTMAN request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfqDX.png)

POSTMAN gets 200/400 reponses, App and Console app gets 401 (Unauthorized). BOTH Apps are .NET CORE apps.

Comment: Define the second parameter of `StringContent` constructor as `Encoding.UTF8`. Complete line of code ---> `request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: As you can see the default http headers in c# are different from Postman.  Solution is to make the c# headers look the same as Postman.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have correct  token.AccessToken ,try to replace

```
 request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
```

with

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
```

Comment: I tried, didn't work. I just wrote to the other side app owners with request information form some insights. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @AurimasKubilius What is did' n work? What is the error now?

Comment: It's just not change anything, the response is still unauthorized.

Comment: @AurimasKubilius It would be nice if you show LogInit and GetToken too

Comment: LogInit just creates a record which will be saved to database table after request. At this time I just take token from POSTMAN request and hardcoding it in (to be sure if token is valid).

Anyway, I have the same problem trying to do request from console app, where is not loginit or getToken methods.

Comment: It would be nice to see how you init http client

Comment: Problem was that I used http instead of https - they gave me bad url's. POSTMAN, somehow, could made request with http, idk why.